# Android Studio Diagrama Visual

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy realizando una aplicación y me ha asaltado una duda.
Digamos que tengo una clase padre que contiene una varios hijos y estos hijos contienen otros, hay una forma de representar ésto gráficamente en la aplicación ?

Por ejemplo algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y obtener buenas respuestas. Es importante [edit] el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado.

Comment: Nuevamente te sugiero revisar [ask] para que edites tu  pregunta ya que has creado otra pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209269/duda-android-crear-%C3%A1rbol-de-objetos